# Terminate Bash script dependent on piped output

Tags: bash, perl, shell, terminate

I have written the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash


counter=0

while [ $counter -lt 250 ]; do
        perl Cumulative_Percentage.pl TP53.lst T1_endo.maf >> OutFile
        perl Optimize_Panel.pl TP53.LST T1_endo.maf >> TP53.lst 
        let counter=counter+1
done
```

And it works well. The problem is that it often runs through far more loops than it needs to. The Perl script, Optimize_Panel.pl, prints a single line if the loop should continue or exits without printing if the loop should stop. 
**I want the while loop to terminate if Optimize_Panel.pl exits instead of printing**... but how?

One possible solution I can imagine is to run

```
wc TP53.lst
```

at the beginning and end of the loop; first setting it to a variable then checking to see if it had increased then leading it to a premature **done** statement if TP53.lst had not been appended. I'm confident that this could work but it feels clunky and I suspect there is a much simpler way to modify the shell script.

Another way I can think of doing this would be to pipe the output of Optimize_Panel.pl into a temporary file then somehow check to see if that file was empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it exit with success/failure exit codes or is the output different only in whether it prints or not?

Comment: bash checks the exit status of the last command with `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`  after that just `then  let counter=counter+1 else exit` ... *etc.*  @rici's is an excellent approach though - that way you don't have to worry about touching the scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the output in a variable, then break out of the loop if that variable is zero-length.

```
while [ $counter -lt 250 ]; do
    perl Cumulative_Percentage.pl TP53.lst T1_endo.maf >> OutFile
    output=$(perl Optimize_Panel.pl TP53.LST T1_endo.maf)
    [ -z "$output" ] && break
    echo "$output" >> TP53.lst 
    let counter=counter+1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple hack (in case the perl script doesn't produce meaningful exit status):

```
perl Optimize_Panel.pl TP53.LST T1_endo.maf | grep . >> TP53.lst || break
```

`grep .` matches any non-empty line, so it is a way of removing empty lines. But it is also a way of detecting whether there were any non-empty lines; it will fail precisely in the case where there weren't any. Of course, it would be much better if the perl script provided an appropriate exit status code (0 for success; non-zero for failure), in which case you could leave out the `| grep .` hack.)

By the way, you can use bash's arithmetic for statement to make your script possibly more readable:

```
for ((counter=0; counter < 250; ++counter)); do
    perl Cumulative_Percentage.pl TP53.lst T1_endo.maf >> OutFile
    perl Optimize_Panel.pl TP53.LST T1_endo.maf |
      grep . >> TP53.lst || break;
done
```

Comment: Very nice - this is shell programming so I don't think this is a "hack" ... except in the sense of "a simple fast correct way to do this". ++